# Comparison between two tab separated files in shell script using awk

Tags: command-line, scripts, text-processing

I've written this code but I am facing the problem as mentioned below.

My Code is:

```
paste 1.txt   2.txt|
awk ' { FS = "\t " } ; NR == 1 { n = NF/2 }
              {for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
                 if($i!=$(i+n))
                   {c = c s i; s = "," }
               if(c)
                 {print "Line No. " NR-1 " COLUMN NO " c;
                  c = "" ; s = "" } } '
```

Expected Output:

```
Line No. 2 COLUMN NO 2,3
Line No. 4 COLUMN NO 1,2,3,4
Line No. 6 COLUMN NO 2,3,4,5
Line No. 7 COLUMN NO 1,2,3,4,5
```

Output that is getting generated:

```
Line No. 2 COLUMN NO 2,3
Line No. 4 COLUMN NO 1,2,3,4
Line No. 6 COLUMN NO 2,3,4,5
Line No. 7 COLUMN NO 1,2,3,4
```

Below specified file is space separated. To understand it better I have formatted it this way.

File1:

```
ID_ID   First_name  Last_name Address                      Contact_Number
ID1     John        Rock      32, Park Lake, California    2222200000
ID2     Tommy       Hill      5322 Otter Lane Middleberge  3333300000
ID3     Leonardo    Test      Half-Way Pond, Georgetown    4444400000
ID8     Rhyan       Bigsh     6762,33 Ave N,St. Petersburg 5555500000
ID50    Steve       Goldberg  6762,33 Ave N,St. Petersburg 6666600000
ID60    Steve       Goldberg                               6666600000
```

File2:

```
ID_ID   First_name  Last_name   Address                      Contact_Number
ID1     John        Rock        32, Park Lake, California    2222200000
ID2     Tommy1      Hill1       5322 Otter Lane Middleberge  3333300000
ID3     Leonardo    Test        Half-Way Pond, Georgetown    4444400000
ID80    Sylvester   Stallone                                 5555500000
ID50    Steve       Goldberg    6762,33 Ave N,St. Petersburg 6666600000
ID60    Mark        Waugh       St. Petersburg               7777700000
ID70    John        Smith                                    8888800000
```

Comment: There are some double tabs in few places. In File1, ID60 in between Goldberg and 6666600000. In FIle2, ID80 in between Stallone and 5555500000, ID70 in between Smith and 8888800000

Comment: The problem I'm facing is till there are equal number of lines it's working fine but in my case I have an extra line in File2, it is generating wrong output only for that line only. It is ignoring that double tab.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hint. The output of:

```
paste 1.txt 2.txt | awk '
{ FS = "\t" }
NR == 1 { n = NF/2 } {
  for(i=1;i<=n;i++) print "\"" $i "\" " ($i == $(i+n) ? "==":"!=") " \"" $(i+n) "\""
  print "###############"
}'
```

which compares and prints every field in every record between files, ends with:

```
"ID60" == "ID60"
"Steve" != "Mark"
"Goldberg" != "Waugh"
"" != "St. Petersburg"
"6666600000" != "7777700000"
###############
"" != "8888800000"
"ID70" != ""
"John" != ""
"Smith" != ""
"" == ""
###############
```

There are two errors:

1. There is an hidden off-by-one error in the case of a line only existing in the second file.  This is because a missing record has *one* field, an empty string before the tab added by `paste`.  Therefore, in this case, you are effectively comparing the fields in the order 5,1,2,3,4.
2. Field 4 is empty for this line in both files (albeit in different ways), so I would have expected the output:

   `Line No. 7 COLUMN NO 1,2,3,5`

To get the exact output you want, the crude fix below will report that all fields don't match if a line is only present in one file.  This can be detected by the `NF == n+1` added to the `if`, because there should be only `n+1` and not `2*n` fields for a line only present in one file, whichever file that is.

```
paste 1.txt 2.txt | awk '
{ FS = "\t" }
NR == 1 { n = NF/2 } {
  for(i=1;i<=n;i++) if(NF == n+1 || $i!=$(i+n)) {c = c s i; s = "," }
  if(c){print "Line No. " NR-1 " COLUMN NO " c; c = "" ; s = "" }
}'
```

This assumes that all records contain the correct number of tabs, `n-1`.